# Visual Studio Windows Emulator

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, emulation, screen-resolution

I'm trying to emulate a high resolution screen for development purposes; however, from looking around, it looks like the VS emulator will only work with Store Apps / UWP.  Is there a way to trick / configure VS into using the emulator for a WPF desktop application?

Alternatively, has anyone found any other, imaginative solution to this kind of issue?

My fallback is to set-up a Hyper-V VM for this, but this feels like overkill for what I need (I'm also not sure I'll be able to set this to the screen ratio that I need).

EDIT:

Having looked into Hyper-V, I can't see any way to configure the display to the desired (portrait) resolution of 2160x3840.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the emulators for this. You want the simulator.

The Windows Simulator creates an RDP session back to the current machine. It simulates the input and output to the session, but it does not emulate the actual code: that's still running on the same machine.

While VS only launches the simulator for you for UWP apps, once it's running you can run other apps such as your WPF app, Visual Studio, remote debugger hosts, etc.

You can also run the simulator explicitly. It should be installed somewhere like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\15.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe`

The emulators are Hyper-V images of the target OS (e.g. Windows 10 Mobile) and won't run your WPF app.

Comment: So your mean we can't test any WPF desktop based app in simulator, despite implemented touch and pinch zoom event?

Comment: when running the simulator explicitly do you have to pass the program name as a parameter? (I tried running it and it ran and then just closed)

Answer (score 0):

If getting a 4k monitor is not an option you need to use something like this.

http://www.hdtvsupply.com/display-emulator.html